# Сборка Qt-приложения

Tags: c++, ubuntu, qt

Установил Qt 4 через центр приложений в Ubuntu 12.10. Первую программу написал и на моем компе она работает нормально, а на чужом не запускает. Рыл в инете и много встречается про статическую сборку. Для новичков не нашел объяснения. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать так, чтобы моя программа работала и на других компьютерах?
В программе инклудится:

- SQLite
- QString
- QDebug
- QWebView (webkit)

UPD: уже понял. думаю дело в архитектуре. я собираю на 64бит, а тестирую на 32битной, пытаюсь скомпилировать для 32бит, пишет следующее:

> /usr/bin/uic-qt4 mainwindow.ui -o ui_mainwindow.h
>   g++ -c -m32 -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -DQT_WEBKIT -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++-32 -I. -I/usr/include/qt4/QtCore -I/usr/include/qt4/QtGui -I/usr/include/qt4 -I. -I. -o main.o main.cpp
>   g++ -c -m32 -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -DQT_WEBKIT -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++-32 -I. -I/usr/include/qt4/QtCore -I/usr/include/qt4/QtGui -I/usr/include/qt4 -I. -I. -o mainwindow.o mainwindow.cpp
>   /usr/bin/moc-qt4 -DQT_WEBKIT -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++-32 -I. -I/usr/include/qt4/QtCore -I/usr/include/qt4/QtGui -I/usr/include/qt4 -I. -I. mainwindow.h -o moc_mainwindow.cpp
>   g++ -c -m32 -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -DQT_WEBKIT -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++-32 -I. -I/usr/include/qt4/QtCore -I/usr/include/qt4/QtGui -I/usr/include/qt4 -I. -I. -o moc_mainwindow.o moc_mainwindow.cpp
>   g++ -m32 -Wl,-O1 -o untitled main.o mainwindow.o moc_mainwindow.o    -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lQtGui -lQtCore -lpthread
>   /usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtGui.so when searching for -lQtGui
>   /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lQtGui
>   /usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so when searching for -lQtCore
>   /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lQtCore
>   /usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so when searching for -lpthread
>   /usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.a when searching for -lpthread
>   collect2: ошибка: выполнение ld завершилось с кодом возврата 1
>   make: *** [untitled] Ошибка 1

UPD 2:

```
$ apt-file search libQtGui.so
fglrx: /usr/share/ati/lib64/libQtGui.so.4
fglrx-updates: /usr/share/ati/lib64/libQtGui.so.4
libqt4-dev: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtGui.so
libqtgui4: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtGui.so.4
libqtgui4: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtGui.so.4.8
libqtgui4: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtGui.so.4.8.3
phantomjs: /usr/lib/phantomjs/libQtGui.so
phantomjs: /usr/lib/phantomjs/libQtGui.so.4
phantomjs: /usr/lib/phantomjs/libQtGui.so.4.8
phantomjs: /usr/lib/phantomjs/libQtGui.so.4.8.2
```

По прежнему также ошибка при компиляции для 32 bit:

```
qmake untitled.pro -r -spec linux-g++-32
make clean
make
```

Comment: раз это убунта (впрочем, это справедливо и для других линукс дистрибутивов), правильнее просто посоветовать установить пакет с qt (не для разработчиков (`*-dev`, а просто).

А статическая линковка - это в данном случае не нужно, как минимум размер файла будет побольше.

Comment: Нужно смотреть, чего не хватает вашей программе. Благое дело в линуксе это очень просто. В консоли пишете `ldd имя_бинарника` (перед этим нужно в каталог с бинарником зайти). Будет видно, какие so файлы используются и каких не удалось найти в системе. Я предполагаю, что не хватает пакета для QWebView.

Comment: Если переносите в виде бинарников, то лучше создать дистрибутивный пакет, deb или rpm, смотря на какую версия линукса переносите, и в нем указать необходимые зависимости. При установке они должны загрузиться и инсталлироваться автоматически.

Comment: А запускали на своей машине или на машине друга? На вашей ничего то и не покажет - оно же запускается.

Comment: в дебиане такие пакеты называются

ia32-libs-gtk ia32-libs

может в убунте так-же

Comment: вот только-что использовал : `sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386`
и ставим эти пакеты для i386 тоже

Answer (score 2):

для работы 32-битных программ в 64-битной операционной системе в случае *debian*-основных дистрибутивов надо [добавить архитектуру *i386*](https://wiki.debian.org/ru/Multiarch/HOWTO):

```
$ sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
```

затем обновить список пакетов:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
```

и установить 32-битные сборки нужных пакетов:

```
$ sudo apt-get install название-пакета:i386
```