# Debian, не ставится пакеты - you have held broken packages

Tags: linux, debian

При попытке поставить пакеты, получаю ошибку, ставлю так:

> apt-get install lib32gcc1

Ошибка

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
lib32gcc1 : Depends: libc6-i386 (>= 2.2.4) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Пробовал не помогло:

```
dpkg --configure -a
apt-get install -f
apt-get autoremove
apt-get autoclean
apt-get clean
apt-get update
dpkg --configure -a
apt-get install -f
```

Какие могут быть причины и как бороться?

Comment: Во-первых, понять, как устроен multilib. Во-вторых, в относительно свежих Debian (да, это некий оксюморон), пакеты lib32* трогать вообще не стоит! Вместо этого надо добавить поддреживаемую архитектуру i386 в конфигурацию apt и ставть пакеты с таким же названием, но i386, например, `apt-get install libgcc-6-dev:i386`, когда `apt-get install libgcc-6-dev` будет эквивалентен `apt-get install libgcc-6-dev:amd64`.

Comment: А по сути вам надо списком указывать все 32-bit библиотеки может поискать старые способы установки Adobe Reader for Linux)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

чтобы устанавливать 32-битные пакеты на 64-битную систему, нынче надо добавить (речь, я так понимаю, про архитектуру intel) архитектуру `i386` как «чужую» (foreign) архитектуру. пример см. в этом ответе: [Сборка Qt-приложения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/441696/178576).

в вашем случае надо **предварительно** вернуть пакетную систему в рабочее состояние, удалив то, что вы попытались наустанавливать. скорее всего, будет достаточно:

```
$ sudo apt-get purge lib32gcc1
```

если нет, дополняйте вопрос сообщениями об ошибках.

Comment: @0andriy Сделал dpkg --add-architecture i386, обновил пакеты. ставлю так apt-get install libgcc-6-dev:i386 или apt-get install lib32gcc1:i368 в ответ пишет, что не может найти такие пакеты

Comment: *lib32gcc1* — зачем вам этот пакет? нынче рулит мультиархитектурность и старые костыли, к которым, как я понимаю, он относится, уже не требуются. // все выполненные команды и их вывод добавьте, пожалуйста, к вопросу, нажав *править* ниже текста вопроса.

Comment: @Drop, и, кстати, на всякий случай приложите и вывод команды `$ dpkg --get-selections | grep hold`

Comment: в репозиториях была проблема. поставил стандартные,выполнил описанные функции и пакет поставился. спасибо