# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS - невозможно устанавливать пакеты - you have held broken packages

Tags: ubuntu, firefox

Версия Ubuntu: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Перестал открываться firefox на ubuntu, выдаваемая ошибка:

```
$ firefox-esr
XPCOMGlueLoad error for file /usr/lib/firefox-esr/libxul.so:
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.23' not found (required by /usr/lib/firefox-esr/libxul.so)
Couldn't load XPCOM.
```

После этого решила установить почему-то исчезнувшие библиотеки, но обнаружила, что ничего не устанавливается вообще. Пример попытки установки любой программы:

```
$ sudo apt-get install synaptic
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 synaptic : Depends: libxapian22 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Стандартные попытки восстановления неустранимых зависимостей ни к чему не приводят

```
sudo apt-get clean
```

Нормально проходит

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Также проходит нормально

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Заканчивается ошибкой. Полный вывод ниже

```
Ign:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise InRelease                                                                                                                                                                                   
Hit:2 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                                                                                                                                                                  
Hit:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/george-edison55/nitroshare/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                                                     
Ign:4 http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise InRelease                                                                                         
Ign:5 https://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable InRelease                                                              
Hit:6 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security InRelease                                                 
Ign:7 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise InRelease                                                                                     
Hit:8 http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise Release                                                                
Hit:9 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-updates InRelease 
Hit:10 https://repo.skype.com/deb stable InRelease                                                                   
Hit:11 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-backports InRelease                                                 
Hit:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gophers/archive/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                               
Hit:13 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise Release                                                            
Get:14 http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise Release.gpg [72 B]                                                          
Ign:14 http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise Release.gpg                                             
Hit:16 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise Release                                             
Ign:17 https://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable Release
Hit:19 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/firefox-esr/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Ign:20 https://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable/main amd64 Packages             
Hit:21 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nilarimogard/webupd8/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Ign:22 https://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable/main i386 Packages              
Hit:23 http://ppa.launchpad.net/philip5/extra/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:24 http://ppa.launchpad.net/strukturag/libde265/ubuntu xenial InRelease    
Ign:25 https://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable/main all Packages               
Hit:26 http://ppa.launchpad.net/strukturag/libheif/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Ign:27 https://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable/main Translation-en_US          
Hit:28 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-mozilla-security/ppa/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Ign:29 https://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable/main Translation-en             
Hit:30 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Ign:31 https://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:32 https://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:20 https://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable/main amd64 Packages
Ign:22 https://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable/main i386 Packages
Ign:25 https://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable/main all Packages
Ign:27 https://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable/main Translation-en_US
Ign:29 https://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable/main Translation-en
Ign:31 https://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:32 https://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:20 https://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable/main amd64 Packages
Ign:22 https://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable/main i386 Packages
Ign:25 https://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable/main all Packages
Ign:27 https://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable/main Translation-en_US
Ign:29 https://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable/main Translation-en
Ign:31 https://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:32 https://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:20 https://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable/main amd64 Packages
Ign:22 https://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable/main i386 Packages
Ign:25 https://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable/main all Packages
Ign:27 https://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable/main Translation-en_US
Ign:29 https://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable/main Translation-en
Ign:31 https://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:32 https://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:20 https://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable/main amd64 Packages
Ign:22 https://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable/main i386 Packages
Ign:25 https://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable/main all Packages
Ign:27 https://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable/main Translation-en_US
Ign:29 https://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable/main Translation-en
Ign:31 https://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:32 https://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Err:20 https://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable/main amd64 Packages
  server certificate verification failed. CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none
Ign:22 https://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable/main i386 Packages
Ign:25 https://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable/main all Packages
Ign:27 https://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable/main Translation-en_US
Ign:29 https://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable/main Translation-en
Ign:31 https://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:32 https://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Fetched 72 B in 35s (2 B/s)
Reading package lists... Done
W: http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/InRelease: Signature by key 630239CC130E1A7FD81A27B140976EAF437D05B5 uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)
W: http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/InRelease: Signature by key 630239CC130E1A7FD81A27B140976EAF437D05B5 uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)
W: http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/InRelease: Signature by key 630239CC130E1A7FD81A27B140976EAF437D05B5 uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)
W: http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/Release.gpg: Signature by key 630239CC130E1A7FD81A27B140976EAF437D05B5 uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)
W: GPG error: http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 16126D3A3E5C1192
W: The repository 'http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise Release' is not signed.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: The repository 'https://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/Release.gpg: Signature by key 630239CC130E1A7FD81A27B140976EAF437D05B5 uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)
E: Failed to fetch https://linux.teamviewer.com/deb/dists/stable/main/binary-amd64/Packages  server certificate verification failed. CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Умоляю, помогите решить проблему. От этого зависит вся моя работа, я просто боюсь перегружать систему

Comment: precise — это 12.04, у вас какой-то бардак в настройках репозиториев

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы устанавливать 32-битные пакеты на 64-битную систему, нынче надо добавить (речь, я так понимаю, про архитектуру intel) архитектуру i386 как «чужую» (foreign) архитектуру. пример см. в этом ответе: Сборка Qt-приложения.

в вашем случае надо предварительно вернуть пакетную систему в рабочее состояние, удалив то, что вы попытались наустанавливать. скорее всего, будет достаточно:

```
$ sudo apt-get purge synaptic
```

Источник:  [похожий вопрос на SO](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/709137/debian-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8B-you-have-held-broken-packages)